Which window design method to choose for a FIR filter design?
I am designing a finite impulse response (FIR) filter with the following specifications:
Passband: [0 kHz, 4 kHz]
Stopband: [6 kHz, 9 kHz]
Passband ripple: 0.5 dB
Minimum stopband attenuation: 30 dB
Sampling frequency: 18 kHz
I have found that Hamming, Hanning, and Blackman windows all meet these criteria for Passband ripple and  Minimum stopband attenuation, but I am unsure which one to choose for my FIR filter design. Could anyone provide guidance on which window might be the best option for this application, considering factors like filter performance, computational efficiency or any other relevant criteria?
Thank you!

maybe look into the Kaiser window.  Since it's a LPF, you're windowing a sinc function.  You might want to adjust the time scaling of the sinc a little besides the length and $\beta$ parameter of the Kaiser window.

If I have to choose from only these three window: Hamming, hanning, and blackman. which one would you suggest?

probably Blackman, maybe Hamming.  BTW, there is no Dr. or Mr. or Ms. Hanning.  I know MATLAB and some other dumb resources label the Hann window as "Hanning".  It's a misnomer.

My preference is the Kaiser Window which is an efficient and close approximation of the DPSS window, providing the best time-bandwidth product for a finite duration sequence. Further, I really like the “beta” knob that the Kaiser window provides, where the dynamic range vs resolution bandwidth can be traded directly (set beta to be zero and the result is the rectangular window, increase beta to drive sidelobes down at the expense of increasing the resolution bandwidth- with this window I believe that you will get the smallest sidelobes for a given resolution bandwidth- hence a great choice for filter design).
My “go-to” approach for linear phase FIR filter design is least-squares resulting in the best filter for most applications I have come across. What is interesting is how close the performance comes to the optimum least-squares solution when I instead use the window design approach and select the Kaiser window as the window. This is my fall-back when the least squares solution doesn’t converge or when I need to determine filter coefficients with the least amount of resources for solving for the coefficients themselves (such as dynamic on-the-fly filters).
The OP is asking which I would choose if I could only choose between Hamming, Hann (aka "Hanning"), or Blackman. Below shows the kernel (DTFT) for each of those three windows showing the comparative frequency performance in terms of frequency resolution versus dynamic range. Given the result shown I would choose Blackman as the increase in dynamic range is well worth the loss in frequency resolution as given by the width of the main lobe (for the same reason I would not choose a rectangular window which itself offers the best frequency resolution but has the poorest dynamic range). However if the application did not require a high stop-band rejection and frequency resolution was the critical parameter, then the Hamming window would be a good choice. Ultimately the details of the specific application should be considered: for example I have found that a simple Hann window serves as an excellent reconstruction filter (much better than Kaiser or any other window) for a higher order sigma delta filter due to the noise shaping characteristics compared to the roll-off factor of the resulting filter.


If I have to choose from only these three window method: Hamming, hanning, and blackman. which one would you suggest?

Updated. I am curious why you are limited to those three?

Hay, Dan, in order to compare apples to apples, I think you should lower the cutoff frequency of the $\mathrm{sinc}(\cdot)$ for the green filter (Blackman).

@robertbristow-johnson I could certainly and then show the relative change in number of coefficients needed to do that. My apples here was the length which I kept the same for all three options and from that we see how the equivalent bandwidth and dynamic range varies for each. (Just a different set of apples)
